# Winforms: Short-cut key text without binding

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, scintilla

Ok so there are many ways to go about fixing my problem. The title describes one.

The problem is that I have made an editor using a smart text box control (ScintillaNET) and I wish to implement an Edit -> Undo button on the menu that also displays its short-cut key in the text. Unfortunately I cannot simply bind it since it will result in the undo event being fired twice (once that the control does on its own, and once by me).

I still need the button to run the undo if it is clicked by the user (as opposed to the short-cut key).

There are 3 ways to fix this that I can see:

- Unbind the key from ScintillaNET control (couldn't find out how to do this).
- Find a way of identifying if the button is clicked or short-cut-keyed.
- Make the appearance of a short-cut key without actually applying one.

Does anyone know how to do one of the above?

I would prefer not to override draw methods and the like.

EDIT:

I was a bit inaccurate about my question. It was actually a ToolStripMenuItem that I needed to check. Sadly it does not have a Focused property.

Comment: You could check the focus. If your button is not focused, then the action has been called from the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Jcl Good answer, shame my question was wrong :( I meant ToolStripMenuItem not button. Sorry.

Comment: @MrUniverse your question is still not clear to me, why can the `undo` be called twice? You should make the context clearer.

Comment: Found it! I set the ShortcutKeyDisplayString in the form's constructor without actually setting a shortcut key.

Comment: @KingKing Like i said, the control fires the undo event on its own.

Answer (score 4):

Found it!

I set the ShortcutKeyDisplayString in the form's constructor without actually setting a shortcut key.

```
public EditorForm()
{
    ....
    undoToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeyDisplayString = "Ctrl+Z";
    ....
}
```